# Using paths on a socket.io MEAN app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io, mean-stack

I'm working on a MEAN app and using Socket.io. As I've been developing the first page (the chess game) it's been working fine.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({ secret: 'chocolatecakepancakesicecream'}));

var html_dir = './html/';

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/chessgame', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(html_dir + 'chessgame.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // ...
}

// ...
```

**chessapp.js**

```
//Load angular
var app = angular.module('chess-game', ['btford.socket-io', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate'])
.factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {
    var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    mySocket = socketFactory({
    ioSocket: myIoSocket
    });

    var mySocket = socketFactory();
    mySocket.forward('select-match-type');
    mySocket.forward('game-event');


return mySocket;
    });

// ...
```

I want to add a new page to monitor stats in the application in real time. I want to connect using a different path to keep the logic seperate. I've tried what I found at http://socket.io/docs/ which is to use .of but it's not working.

**server.js (with paths)**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({ secret: 'chocolatecakepancakesicecream'}));

var html_dir = './html/';

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/chessgame', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(html_dir + 'chessgame.html');
});

var chess = io.of('/chess');
var stats = io.of('/stats');

chess.on('connection', function (socket) {

// ...

}

stats.on('connection', function (socket) {

// ...

}

// ...
```

**chessapp.js (with path)**

```
//Load angular
var app = angular.module('chess-game', ['btford.socket-io', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate'])
.factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {
    var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {path: '/chess'});

    mySocket = socketFactory({
    ioSocket: myIoSocket
    });

    var mySocket = socketFactory();
    mySocket.forward('select-match-type');
    mySocket.forward('game-event');
    return mySocket;
});
```

I don't get any kind of error from node when I run this code but no connection is ever made. I believe the client side part is working because I can see in the console that requests are made to localhost:3000/chess but the result is 404 not found.

If anyone can tell me the correct way of setting up paths with angular/node/socket.io or tell me where I'm going wrong, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I don't think that the .of function creates the route for you as well. Your server only has a route for '/chessgame' not '/chess'. In your server.js file you have to add a 'chess' route:

```
app.get('/chess', function...
```

Also, does it work if you use:

```
io.on('connection'...
```

Instead of chess.on?

Comment: Yes. It works normally with io.on. By adding app.all('/chess', function..) I'm not getting a 404 error anymore but now getting this: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: About it 'working' when I use just io.on (the log shows a connection being made) - I think it does that because I see the client requesting http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/ aswell as http://localhost:3000/chess